# Writing Out a Textbox Produces Unexpected Results

Tags: c#, listbox, tostring

I have created 2 text boxes that take the name and email address, stores it in a "**text**" file and display the contents in a list box.  I have everything done but when it displays in the list box this is the output that I get.

> "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: tony"
>   "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: tony@tony.com"

Can anyone tell me why it is doing that please? I'm still new to c# and I know this is a minor thing I just do not know where to look

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace _iLab_Week7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {  
        private StreamReader inFile; //streamreader for input
        private StreamWriter outFile;  //streamwriter for output

        const string filename = "contacts.txt";

        public Form1()
        {          
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAddContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Disable the "add contact" and "email" 
            btnAddContact.Enabled=false;
            txtBoxEmail.Enabled=false;

            //check for and create contacts.txt file
            if(!File.Exists(filename))
                File.Create(filename);

            if(File.Exists(filename))
            {
                try
                {
                    //create the file stream
                    outFile = new StreamWriter(filename, true);

                    //get the item from the name and email text box
                    //write it to the file
                    outFile.WriteLine(txtBoxName);
                    outFile.WriteLine(txtBoxEmail + "\n");

                    //close the file
                    outFile.Close();

                    //clear the textbox
                    txtBoxName.Text="";
                    txtBoxEmail.Text="";

                    //the cursor in the text box
                    txtBoxName.Focus();
                    txtBoxEmail.Focus();
                }
                catch (DirectoryNotFoundException exc)
                {
                     lstBoxContact.Items.Add(exc.Message);
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException exc)
                {
                    lstBoxContact.Items.Add(exc.Message);
                }

                string listItem;
                this.lstBoxContact.Items.Clear();
                btnAddContact.Enabled = false;

                try
                {
                    //open file for reading
                    inFile=new StreamReader(filename);
                    //read from file and add to list box
                    while ((listItem=inFile.ReadLine()) !=null)
                    {
                       this.lstBoxContact.Items.Add(listItem);
                    }
                    //Close the file
                    inFile.Close();
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException exc)
                {
                   this.lstBoxContact.Items.Add(exc);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.lstBoxContact.Items.Add("File Unabailable");
            }

        }

        private void lstBoxContact_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //enable button
            btnAddContact.Enabled = true;
            txtBoxName.Enabled = true;
            txtBoxEmail.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            //make sure files are closed
            try
            {
                inFile.Close();
                outFile.Close();
            }
            catch { }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: you need to post the code.. without which it will be difficult for us to tell anything. It seems like you are saving the textbook object rather than saving textbox content....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
outFile.WriteLine(txtBoxName);
outFile.WriteLine(txtBoxEmail + "\n");
```

with

```
outFile.WriteLine(txtBoxName.Text);
outFile.WriteLine(txtBoxEmail.Text + "\n");
```

and try...

**ADDED** : When you say `txtBoxName`, you are referring to the `txtBoxName` **object** as a whole, which contains many properties - like Text, ForeColor, Font etc.... To get only the value or content, you need to specify the property which gives you that - which is the `Text` property

More about [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly. Can you give me a quick explanation as to why I have to use the .Text after the object name please.

Comment: @Monti see the updated answer... mark it s answer if it solves your issue

Comment: Will do thanks for the help. I'm still new this site. Just started learning C# this semester.

Answer (score 0):

```
outFile.WriteLine(txtBoxName);
```

is equivalent to

```
outFile.WriteLine(txtBoxName.ToString());
```

For most classes, the `ToString()` method is the same as `Object.ToString()`. This method just displays the name of the type of the instance you're trying to display. So you might have only seen

> System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

However, the `TextBox` class helpfully overrides this method and displays both the type name and the value of the `Text` property.

But as Saagar Elias Jacky said. This is not what you actually intended to do, so just display `txtBoxName.Text` as he suggested.